# Report expiry date of certificates used by Azure application gateway using resources graph explorer

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

As captioned. Is it possible to report expiry date of certificates used by Azure application gateway using resources graph explorer? If yes, what should be the query?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get it from resource graph explorer. you can get the details from CLI or power shell
[az network application-gateway ssl-cert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/ssl-cert?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_application_gateway_ssl_cert_list)